# Serilog OpenSearch configuration failure troubleshooting

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, serilog, opensearch

I'm struggling with connecting to my AWS Open Search domain with Serilog. I'm using the Serilog Sinks OpenSearch NuGet package. I'm working in C# .NET 7.0.

Using the AWS AwsSigV4HttpConnection. I can connect, create an index, and create a document. But when I try and use Serilog Sinks OpenSearch (Modify Connection Settings). I get no errors, no documents and no logs. Any help would be very appreciated.
I did try to add these three lines to get more debugging info but no dice.

```
Debugger.Launch();
AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogTo = LoggingOptions.Console;
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
```

I believe the Modify Connection Settings is failing. But I have no indication. Or it's failing because it's not finding the correct index? Or it's not adding a new document?

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Map("{logs}", "**error**", (name, writeTo) =>
    {
        var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
        var currentWeek = myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now,
            CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
            DayOfWeek.Monday);
        writeTo.OpenSearch(new OpenSearchSinkOptions(endpoint)
        {
            ModifyConnectionSettings = conn =>
            {
                var httpConnection = new AwsHttpConnection({credentials}, {RegionEndpoint});
                var conf = new OpenSearch.Net.ConnectionConfiguration(new Uri("{.amazonaws.com/}"), connection);
                return conf;
            },
            ConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            TypeName = "_doc",
            IndexFormat = $"my-index-{currentYear}-{currentWeek}",
            MinimumLogEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Information,
            EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback |
            EmitEventFailureHandling.ThrowException,
            FailureCallback = e =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                "An error occured in Serilog OpenSearch sink: " +
                $"{e.Exception?.Message} | {e.Exception?.InnerException?.Message}")
            });
        });
        Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
Log.Verbose("Hello World!");
```

I am a newbie to AWS OpenSearch and Elasticsearch in general so, my questions may not be great. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome Jason. Sadly, we're missing reproducible steps here - what is the value of `connection` and the value of `endpoint` that you're using here? What region are you trying to connect to etc. If we have a bit more information, we can try our best to help. Can you also link to the Nuget package you're referring to? And as a general tip, make the code minimal. In this case, for example, remove the logic for getting current date and hardcode it :) thanks